# How Interrogate Variables Higher in Calling Stack (without Passing Arguments)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.6.x, and above, is there a way to reference (interrogate) a local variable contained in a function that is higher in the calling stack than the function that needs to perform an interrogation—without passing the variables as arguments?

For example:

```
def lowest_leaf():
    #Is there a way to access a_value and/or b_value 
        #from lowest_leaf() WITHOUT passing them as arguments into 
        #this function?
    #HERE: print(a_value)
    #HERE: print(b_value)
    return(0)


def middle_leaf(a_value):
    print(a_value)
    b_value = a_value * 2
    lowest_leaf()
    return(0)


def root_leaf():
    a_value = 10
    middle_leaf(a_value)
    return(0)

if '__name__' == '__main__':
    root_leaf()
```

Many, *many* thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Likely not without doing something super sketchy. Why note just pass the data? That seems entirely possible here, and will make your code much cleaner.

Comment: Functions should not be dependent on being called from specific functions. You shouldn't require the calling function having variables with specific names. I agree, everything that the function needs should be passed as parameters.

Comment: You could also define `lowest_leaf()` as a nested function inside `middle_leaf()`. Then it can access the outer variables.

Comment: You can use call-stack inspection, but **you really shouldn't be doing that here**. Essentially, you would be (hackily) creating dynamic scoping, but why? Just pass the values as arguments to your function. That is *the way to do this*.

Comment: Making all functions uselessly return 0 and refusing to pass arguments demonstrates a misunderstanding of the fundamentals of functions.

Comment: Yes, why are your functions returning `0`? Yu never do anything with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

I would emphasise that this is generally a dodgy thing to do because it breaks encapsulation, as noted in the comments. Unless you have a very good reason for doing this (and if you need to think whether you do, you **don't**), I would suggest redesigning your application.

Nevertheless, Python is built around the idea that we are all consenting adults, and consequently you can do what you want with `inspect`:

```
import inspect

def lowest_leaf():
    middle_leaf_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    print(middle_leaf_frame.f_locals)
    root_leaf_frame = middle_leaf_frame.f_back
    print(root_leaf_frame.f_locals)

def middle_leaf(a_value):
    b_value = a_value * 2
    lowest_leaf()

def root_leaf():
    a_value = 10
    middle_leaf(a_value)

root_leaf()
```

Output:

```
{'a_value': 10, 'b_value': 20}
{'a_value': 10}
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate I agree fully, but I am not sure that the experience/inexperience of the question's asker should affect whether the question should be answered. If someone who honestly really needed this performed a search and came to this question, I'd think they'd want a solution. (I bolded "don't" for more emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is super helpful but this is the only way I see the objective being achieved.
Basically we define a class.

```
class tree:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def lowest_leaf(self):
        #Is there a way to access a_value and/or b_value 
            #from lowest_leaf() WITHOUT passing them as arguments into 
            #this function?
        #HERE: print(a_value)
        #HERE: print(a_value)
        print(self.a_value)
        print(self.b_value)
        return(0)


    def middle_leaf(self,a_value):
        self.b_value = a_value * 2
        self.lowest_leaf()
        return(0)


    def root_leaf(self):
        self.a_value = 10
        self.middle_leaf(self.a_value)
        return(0)

tree1 = tree() # we define the tree here
tree1.root_leaf() # we can run any method we want.
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
10
20
```